# Typescript async await not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I have the following async function in Typescript, and it seems that await doesn't block and yield the required result as I expect.

```
async function getCroppedImgContent(origImgBuffer: Buffer) {
  console.log("Inside setCroppedImgContent");
  let croppedBuffer =  await sharp(origImgBuffer)
    .resize(4000, 4000)
    .max()
    .toBuffer();
  console.log("After crop");

  return croppedBuffer;
}
```

"After crop" is not print immediately after "Inside setCroppedImgContent", but a lot later. Looks like await is not working.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Does `sharp().resize().max().toBuffer()` return a promise because `await` is only really useful when you are awaiting a promise.

Comment: The execution is not blocked at the await line, result is returned later

Comment: Yes, it returns Promise. I have checked it in debugger.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, it does: [https://github.com/lovell/sharp#examples](https://github.com/lovell/sharp#examples)

Comment: Are you `await`ing the promise returned from `getCroppedImgContent`?

Comment: @Nenad - It sounds like it is working properly to me.  What is the actual problem?  It will execute `sharp().resize().max().toBuffer() ` and then await that returned promise.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code, `After setCroppedImgContent` is printed before `After crop`, because you're working with async code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Isn't the purpose of async/await to execute the code synchronously. await should block execution until sharp returns cropped buffer and "After crop" should be print immediately after "Inside setCroppedImgContent"

Comment: You need to move `After setCroppedImgContent` inside last `then` to get correct print output.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of async/await ?

Comment: I'm confused about your question.  Please add to your question the EXACT order that all your log statements appear.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the order is "Inside setCroppedImgContent", "After setCroppedImgContent", some other non related logs, "After crop",  "Set image content". It looks like await has no effect on the execution.

Comment: Please put the exact log order IN YOUR QUESTION (you can use the edit link to modify it).  What you have their now is not very clear and important info should be in the question for others to easily see, not in comments.  Also, please add the calling code to your question and include it's log messages in the log sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Nenad, the fact that you used `await` inside your function does not mean it will be executed synchronously. `await` just makes the execution be blocked for a single call.

If you want `console.log("After setCroppedImgContent");` to be executed after `getCroppedImgContent` is completed you need to `await` its call:

```
await getCroppedImgContent(origContent)
    .then(function (croppedBuffer) {
    image.content = croppedBuffer;
    console.log("Set image content");
});
```

Comment: But in this case this code should be added to a new function, and marked with `async` keyword.

Comment: What about "After crop", shouldn't it be printed after "Inside setCroppedImgContent" ? In my case it isn't, and that's my biggest problem. I have added the calling code because of the comments, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: Now you changed your description completely, and it seems what I would consider correct behaviour.

Comment: "After crop" is not printed immediately because the execution is blocked waiting for the Promise to be completed.